# Console program doesn't react on sending \n to stdin

Tags: java, process, console, stdin

I'm writing GUI using JAVA for a console program. It starts and works well, but when i send "\n" or "\r\n" to it's stdin it doesn't react as it reacts if i simply start this program in Terminal and press "Enter".

This code is used to start process:

```
String cmd="example.exe";
process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
```

And this code is used to send "\n"

```
OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write("\n".getBytes());
outputStream.flush();
```

In other thread i'm trying to read from this process

```
while ((line = is.readLine()) != null && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    ...
}
```

How can i properly send "\n" to receive information from the process?

Update:
I need to send a new line symbol. Or "Press Enter".
I read out and error, both are empty.
Application always reports it's status as reaction to pressing enter. So no reaction is a bug.

Comment: Use any character stream that can interpret it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  To get good help, you probably need to specify what you expect to happen - why would you expect this to behave any differently to how it does? What do you want to happen?  Do you want the "receiving" thread to be sent the byte code of "\n"?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are expecting the newline written to `outputStream` to trigger something that you can read using `is`.

Here are a couple of possible causes:

1. You could be reading from the wrong stream.  The external program might be writing to "standard error" and you are reading "standard output" or vice-versa.
2. The external application might be failing to flush.  For example, it (or the I/O library it uses) might only flush output after each newline if the output is directed to an interactive output stream (e.g. a "console").  The pipe connecting program output to your JVM might not show up as interactive.

These are only guesses ...

---

If I was trying to debug this, I would try to determine whether the problem is that the newline doesn't get to `example.exe`, that the response doesn't get written / flushed by `example.exe`, or that the Java side is failing to read it ... for some reason.